# How to consolidate macro results

Tags: splunk

I have two macros a and b, both output a table.

How can I create a query to get a table with consolidated results of both macros?

Comment: It will be hard to say how without seeing the content of the two macros...

Comment: @LarryShatzer - both macros returns a table like this: date | severity ... in the end I want to have the same table layout but combined wit the results of both macros :-)

Comment: It's not about how the macros format the data, but what they do. It would also be good to see the whole search before the macros, and after.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without the macros your are using but I think you could use the [append](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/7.2.3/SearchReference/Append) function :

```
`macro1\` | append [`macro2`] | table fieldNames1 fieldNames2 ...
```

This will append the events from both searches and create a new table.

**EDIT (to answer comment)**:

You could try the return function to dynamically create your search:

```
|inputlookup lookupname | search component_name=componentName |eval macros = "`".macro_name."`"| return 999 $macros
```

Will retrun `macro1` `macro2`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for this approach. One more question: If I have these macro names in a lookup file, how can I append them dynamically? So ... have a lookup file with two columns: "component_name" and "macro_name". For the same component name, I have two lines with different macro_names (macro1 and macro2) ... how can I list all macro_names from the loopup file to create a dynamic append for macros? Hope that explanation is to understand :-)